# Excel get dynamic range of month from dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sheet.

please see

[image]

where I have a list of days in the first row. I need to get the Monthly Range using a formula. For example, the formula output should be **B1:S1** (range of March) when the input is given as **3** (third month). I can't use any VBA it should be an excel formula.

Comment: I would use indirect() and build the range with month(), with a logical test to find when the month changes from 2 to 3 or 3 to 4.

Comment: Any example would be really helpful

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem. Why do you want the range address? What's the goal here. Also, make an honest attempt and edit your question with your formula for debugging purposes to make this on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you could use this formula:

```
=LET(monthrange,FILTER(1:1;MONTH(1:1)=3),
firstDay,ADDRESS(3,MATCH(MIN(monthrange),1:1,0)),
lastDay,ADDRESS(3,MATCH(MAX(monthrange);1:1,0)),
firstDay & ":" & lastDay
```

- first step filters the first row for all march dates.
- second step returns the address of the lowest date,
- third step the address of last date of march.
- Last step joins them to a range

This could/should be enhanced in case there is more than one year in row 1
Propably you will also want to use a cell or whatever to specify the month.

[image]

Comment: I get the error "The first argument of LET must be a valid name"

Comment: This formula is working. I replaced ; with ,

=LET(monthrange,FILTER(1:1,MONTH(1:1)=3),firstDay,ADDRESS(3,MATCH(MIN(monthrange),1:1,0)),lastDay,ADDRESS(3,MATCH(MAX(monthrange),1:1,0)),firstDay&":"&lastDay)

Comment: @PubuduThelahera the ; and , is just a system setting that varies between country and language settings - so not an error we really worry about, just something we all adjust for when we look at answers.

Comment: I corrected the formula - now it should work on an english system